# Visualise a C# method logic

Tags: c#, business-logic

I have a complex C# method which contains a set of if statements which determine access rights for a user.

I am looking for a way to visualise this logic into, say, a workflow diagram or something similar.

This is using .NET 3.5 and Visual Studio 2010.

Which tools (preferrably freely available) are available that may do this?

NB: I have found lots of tools to visualise method calls (eg call hierarchy), this isn't what I am looking for. I am looking for a tool to visualise the logic.

Thanks

EDIT: As part of my investigation I did find Flowchart4C# but it is $200 to buy outright and the trial won't let me confirm it does what I want it to! (<5 conditional statements).

Comment: Just to be clear, you're looking for an automated tool right?

Comment: Sounds like you may want to refactor this massive method so that the main part reads like plain English as a start.

Comment: I would not try. First, write unit tests that cover the paths and verify current behavior. Second, use automated refactoring tools to clarify the code by extracting methods, etc.

Comment: @Drackir - That's correct.  @Marco and @TrueWill : It may be ideal to do this, however in my scenario it is of more value to leave the if statements as they are. But I do agree your points are valid. :)

Comment: The method reads reasonably well, it is more the depth of the conditions that I would find a map very useful. :)

Comment: @TrueWill, do you have a good way to mock LDAP?

Comment: [Steps on a chair] @Russel, if you are here it means that there has to be some value in sorting out the method's logic. Long list of if statements are typical code smells and there are refactoring patterns that will make you happy and may shed some light on the underlying structure.[Steps down].

Comment: @Marco, do you think 4-level deep if statements needs refactoring? You are absolutely right the map is to try to sort out (and validate)  the logic.

Comment: 4-level nesting? Ohh yess. It needs refactoring. I'm never nesting more than two levels (method and one `if`). My experience is that more levels can give you hell when you have released the application and start maintaining it (and have forgotten why you did as you did).

Comment: @Marco - I'd create a wrapper class that handles the direct LDAP calls, integration-test that, then hang an interface off it. Just expose the simplest functionality/API that you need. Put the business logic in another class that depends on the interface using Inversion of Control. But you may want to post that as a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refactor your method: here are some suggestions for dealing with conditionals

http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html
http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html

but probably this is best

http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithVisitor.html

Comment: Thanks @Marco - I found the guard clauses most relevant -  I have sets of tasks assigned to fluid user types.

Comment: Question: Refactoring the logic into separate methods is one way of negating the need for a map. My function is performance critical (being a security check every time a web request is made) would breaking it into multiple methods hurt the performance?

Comment: I would trust the compiler to optimize the function calls. Unless there is much copying of data in passing parameters, I would prefer readable code first, and worry about performance later if needed.

Comment: @Russell - there is a section in Bill Wagner's book [Effective C#](http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Covers-4-0-Specific-Development/dp/0321658701) (both editions) called **"Prefer Small, Simple Functions."** It goes into detail about how the JIT compiler can create **more** efficient code if you program this way.

Answer (score 1):

Non-automatic: Use [dia](http://dia-installer.de/) (Windows, Linux: has flowchart-templates) or [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) (Windows, Linux, Mac: vector graphics).

Automatic: Refactor first, then automate.

Comment: Thanks @Leonidas - I agree Dia is a great free tool. :) I am working on mapping it out automatically ideally.